# wp_mail() not working for WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp

I have a plugin which sends an email on clicking a button. Known that there are no issues with the form (as the data is getting stored in the DB perfectly) what could possibly be wrong in this code snippet that it can't send an e-mail to either client or admin.
If there's no issues with the form could the problem be with `SMTP`, which is unlikely because Contact Form 7 is perfectly sending mail to both client and admin.

The function `wte_enquiry_send_mail()` is the one sending email using `wp_mail()` function.

```
function wte_enquiry_send_mail()
{
    $email = sanitize_email( $_POST['enquiry_email'] );
    $wp_travel_engine_settings = get_option( 'wp_travel_engine_settings',true );
    $name = esc_attr( $_POST['enquiry_name'] );
    $country = isset( $_POST['enquiry_country'] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['enquiry_country'] ):'N/A';
    $contact = esc_attr( $_POST['enquiry_contact'] );
    $adult = isset( $_POST['enquiry_adult'] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['enquiry_adult'] ):'N/A';
    $children = isset( $_POST['enquiry_children'] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['enquiry_children'] ):'N/A';
    $message1 = esc_attr( $_POST['enquiry_message'] );
    $postid = get_post( $_POST['enquiry_pid'] );
    $slug = $postid->post_name;
    $url = '<a href='.esc_url( get_permalink( $postid ) ).'>'.esc_attr( $slug ).'</a>';
    $subject = isset( $wp_travel_engine_settings['query_subject'] ) ? esc_attr( $wp_travel_engine_settings['query_subject'] ):'Enquiry received';
    $admin_email = get_option ('admin_email');
    $to = sanitize_email($admin_email);
    $email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';
    $headers[] = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$admin_email .'>';
    $headers[] = 'Reply-To: '.$name.' <'.$email .'>';
    $message = __("Name: ","wp-travel-engine"). $name.'<br/>';
    $message.= __("Country: ","wp-travel-engine"). $country.'<br/>';
    $message.= __("Trip: ",'wp-travel-engine'). $url.'<br/>';
    $message.= __("Email: ","wp-travel-engine"). $email.'<br/>';
    $message.= __("Contact: ",'wp-travel-engine'). $contact.'<br/>';
    $message.= __("Adult: ","wp-travel-engine"). $adult.'<br/>';
    $message.= __("Children: ",'wp-travel-engine'). $children.'<br/>';
    $message.= __("Message: ",'wp-travel-engine'). $message1.'<br/>';

    add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '));

    if ( strpos( $wp_travel_engine_settings['email']['emails'], ',') !== false ) {
            $wp_travel_engine_settings['email']['emails'] = str_replace(' ', '', $wp_travel_engine_settings['email']['emails']);
        $admin_emails = explode( ',', $wp_travel_engine_settings['email']['emails'] );

        foreach ( $admin_emails as $key => $value ) {
                $admin_sent = wp_mail( $value, $subject, $message, $headers );
            }
    }
    else{
        $wp_travel_engine_settings['email']['emails'] = str_replace(' ', '', $wp_travel_engine_settings['email']['emails']);
        $admin_sent = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
    }
```

I expect an automatic email to both client and admin after the form is filled up.

Comment: Dump the value of `$admin_sent`. If it's `true`, the function is working. If it's `false`, then something is failing. If it's `true` but you're not receiving it, check your server logs to see if it's actually being sent or if it's bouncing, being rejected, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, checked the server logs and found the issue is on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Xhynk rightly pointed out to me to check the server logs.
I did and realised there's an SMTP error due to the Sender Domain Policies of my host.

> If your website is example.com and you have a PHP mail form sending email, the FROM address in that email must be something like contact@example.com. Emails that are sent from the web server using a FROM address from somewhere else (such as Yahoo or Google) will be blocked and never sent.

I was using G-mail, as soon as I changed it things worked.